# Guzzle retrieve form_params from response object

Tags: php, api, guzzle

I am trying to write a unit test for a GraphQL call but it is failing due to the "form_params" field not matching the GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Stream Object contents. I was looking at an existing unit test that uses a REST api call and am trying to print out the contens of its "form_params" using Guzzle. Couldn't find anything in the docs

```
$url = \GuzzleHttp\uri_template($url[0], $url[1]);

        $options = [
            'form_params' => [
                'enrollment[user_id]' => 'sis_user_id:' . $userId,
                'enrollment[type]' => $enrollmentType,
                'enrollment[enrollment_state]' => $enrollmentState,
                'enrollment[role_id]' => $role_id
            ]
        ];

//the response 
$response = $this->client->post($url, $options);
var_dump($response->getBody()->getContents()); // trying to get form_params
```

The dump line gives me this which is similar to the form_params but not quite

```
"{"sis_section_id":"Section-S15-99190","type":"TeacherEnrollment","role":null,"user":{"id":1,"sis_user_id":234,"login_id":"thackerj","name":"Jeremy Thacker"},"grades":{"unposted_current_grade":null,"unposted_final_grade":null}}"
```

Comment: Please don't use `\GuzzleHttp\uri_template()` function, it will be removed in future versions of Guzzle

Answer (score 0):

```
$client = new Client([
    'headers' => [
        'Accept' => 'application/json',
        'Content-Type' => 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
    ]
]);
```